# Shirink the numpy array with max

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy array such as np.array([2,2])

```
[[1,9],
[7,3]]
```

I want to get the max of third demention and make this into one dimension.

then numpy.array should be like this  `[9,7]`

I think I can do this with for loop and make another numpy.

However it looks ackword, is there any good way to do this ?

Comment: But the array you provide is 2d. Where is the third dimension?

Comment: SOrry, it's second dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[amax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) function (alias is `np.max`)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,9],
[7,3]])

np.amax(a, axis=1)  

# array([9, 7])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use max with specific axis. In this example axis is 1.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,9],
                [7,3]])

arr_max = np.max(arr, axis=1)
print(arr_max)
```

Output:

```
[9 7]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I checked the fastest answer as final answer, but I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.max` is just an **alias** for `numpy.amax`. This function only works on a single input array and finds the value of maximum element in that entire array (returning a scalar). Alternatively, it takes an **axis** argument and will find the maximum value along an axis of the input array (returning a **new array**).

```
import numpy

np_array = numpy.array([[1,9],
                [7,3]])

max_array = numpy.max(np_array, axis=1)

print(max_array.shape)
print(max_array)
```

Output:

```
(2,)
[9 7]
```

Comment: Thank you for your deeper help. I can solve the problem